# Do Sphinx wordforms need to include all permutations or do the process in order?

Tags: sphinx

if I have a record in my db

- 6th Ave

and the following Sphinx Wordforms:

```
Sixth > 6th
Ave > Avenue
6th Avenue > Avenue of Americas
```

and I make 'the' a stopword

Will Sixth Avenue still match the '6th Ave' record since:

- Sixth=6th
- Avenue=Ave?

Will Ave of the Americas return my records since:

- Ave = Avenue
- Avenue of the Americas = Avenue of Americas
- Avenue of the Americas = 6th Avenue

Answer (score 0):

I think "Sixth Avenue" will work and will return "6th Ave" record.
But query "Ave of the Americas" will not return "6th Ave" record.